# Hyperref and theoremstyle break: red box drawn on line above

Tags: hyperref, ntheorem

I am using the hyperref package in my document for links and ntheorem for theorems. I want to use the "break" theoremstyle that gives a line break after the theorem label. But then using references in the first line of my theorem will cause hyperref to overdraw the red box.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem}
    An interesting lemma!
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Some description]
    Here we refer to lemma \ref{lem}. This causes the red box to overdraw.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
    Here, we need some more space to get into the second line, but then the link to our lemma \ref{lem} does not pose a problem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of the MWE]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried loading `hyperref` after `ntheorem`?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have tried that but it does not change the output.

Comment: Try `\mbox{\ref{lem}}` instead of the reference.

Comment: If that solved your problem consider accepting the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround your `\ref` with a `\mbox`. In the following example there's an own command for that.

[image: boxes]

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcommand{\lref}[1]{\mbox{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem}
    An interesting lemma!
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Some description]
    Here we refer to lemma \lref{lem}. This causes the red box to overdraw.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
    Here, we need some more space to get into the second line, but then the link to our lemma \lref{lem} does not pose a problem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The height and depth of the surrounding box is used to get height and depth of the annotation rectangle in case of driver `pdftex`. The surrounding box for the link in Lemma 2 includes the Lemma title line and the descender of `f` in `refer`. The theorem is implemented differently, thus the current height is much smaller.

The rectangles can be more tight by surrounding the links with smaller boxes, `\mbox`. The third link in the row increases the box by `\vphantom` to get a more uniform height and depth. Then the rectangles for link texts `1`, `m`, `g` would share the same height and depth.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem}
    An interesting lemma!
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Some description]
    Here we refer to lemma
    \ref{lem}/\mbox{\ref{lem}}/\mbox{\vphantom{g\"A}\ref{lem}}.
    This causes the red box to overdraw.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
    Here, we need some more space to get into the second line,
    but then the link to our lemma
    \ref{lem}/\mbox{\ref{lem}}/\mbox{\vphantom{g\"A}\ref{lem}}
    does not pose a problem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]