# Hyperref phrase with pagebreak also makes footnotes hyperlinked

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, page-breaking, hyperlink

With the command \hyperref[link]{text} from the hyperref package, if the text breaks across pages and the first page has a footnote, then that footnote is erroneously also made a hyperlink.

Looks like a bug to me. Any elegant suggestions for fixes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum,amsmath}

\begin{document}

First an equation:
\begin{equation}
    x=y
    \label{eq}
\end{equation}
Now, a sentence.\footnote{A footnote.}

\lipsum[1-4]

\hyperref[eq]{Finally, a sentence hyperlinked to the equation above; because this hyperref-ed sentence breaks across the page, the unrelated footnote also becomes hyperlinked.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/2388

Comment: Thanks, that partly explains where the issue comes from. Still curious (a) whether there's a fix in TeX Live 2020 (still used e.g. by arXiv) and (b) whether the problem is gone in (hyperref in) TeX Live 2021 (I can't check myself).

Comment: no, I now no fix for older texlive, and the output routine hasn't be adapted yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info!