# fix for pagebreak in hyperlink does not work for footnotes

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, page-breaking, texlive, hyperlink

I thought the problem from [Hyperref phrase with pagebreak also makes footnotes hyperlinked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599400/hyperref-phrase-with-pagebreak-also-makes-footnotes-hyperlinked), [How do I forbid pagebreaks inside urls without forbidding linebreaks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578373/how-do-i-forbid-pagebreaks-inside-urls-without-forbidding-linebreak) and  [Page breaks in hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646704/page-breaks-in-hyperlinks) seems to be kind of fixed by the solution explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/128042.

But when the page-break is interrupted by a footnote the following code still results in the footnote being falsely linked (both for TeXLive 2021 and TeXLive 2022 in Overleaf):

Check the code and the resulting pdf in Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/brdtdxcgkzbw

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,xpatch,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
%patches for texlive 2021/current miktex
\xpatchcmd\@outputpage{\vfil\color@hbox}{\vfil\pdfrunninglinkoff\color@hbox}{}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd\@outputpage{{\@thehead}\color@endbox}{{\@thehead}\color@endbox\pdfrunninglinkon}{}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd\@outputpage{\footskip\color@hbox\normalcolor}{\footskip\color@hbox\normalcolor\pdfrunninglinkoff}{}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd\@outputpage{{\@thefoot}\color@endbox}{{\@thefoot}\pdfrunninglinkon\color@endbox}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

A\footnote{AaAaAa}

B

C\label{c}

\vspace{410pt}

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \hyperref[c]{Ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc cccccccc cccccccccccc cccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc }
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\insert\footins{\pdfrunninglinkoff}\footnote{AaAaAa}\insert\footins{\pdfrunninglinkon}` should work.

Comment: Where do I have to add this?

Comment: Ah, I see, I just have to replace "`\footnote{AaAaAa}`" with your code "`\insert\footins{\pdfrunninglinkoff}\footnote{AaAaAa}\insert\footins{\pdfrunninglinkon}`". Thank you this works :)

Comment: This does not work if `\thanks` is used instead of `\footnote` or do you have a fix for that too?

Comment: put the insert command before and after \maketitle.